# Resource injection issue JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I try to achieve `resource injection` for a long time but couldn't succeeded.

I use `JSF 2.2`,  `JDK 1.7.` And my ide is `eclipse luna`.

I have a session scoped bean called `UserBean` and view scoped bean called `SettingsBean`.

I set them in `faces-config.xml` UserBean as `session scoped` and SettingsBean as `view scoped` with their bean name "`settingsBean`" and "`userBean`"

```
public class SettingsBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject  // I also tried @ManagedProperty but didn't work
    private UserBean userBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){         
        System.out.println(userBean.getUser().getFullName());
    }

   public UserBean getUserBean() {
        return userBean;
    }

    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
        this.userBean = userBean;
    }

}
```

The problem is I get userBean as null. What is the problem here? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: show UserBean and also the imports of both classes.

Comment: Depends on a number of things. First you need to make sure all your annotations are aligned and from the proper packages. Then make sure you have a properly defined "beans.xml" file in your project. Then you also need to understand that the current `@ViewScoped` implementation for CDI is still buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed `ManagedBean` and `ViewScoped` definitions in faces-config.xml for `settingsBean` and added them in `SettingsBean.java` file manually.

And added this also:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{userBean}")   
    private UserBean userBean;
```

So finally, it works:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class SettingsBean implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @ManagedProperty(value="#{userBean}")   
        private UserBean userBean;  
        //...
 @PostConstruct
    public void init(){         
        System.out.println(userBean.getUser().getFullName());
    }
    public UserBean getUserBean() {
            return userBean;
        }

        public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
            this.userBean = userBean;
        }
}
```